# Why is my collection view cell so hard to tap?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionViewController and multiple cells. However when I seem to tap onto one of those cells I would need multiple taps before the `didSelectItemAt` would read. My cells are spaced out evenly, at least big enough for them to be tapped on. I only get this problem on a real device and not on the simulator.

Here is my code

```
class TimeAvailabilityCell:UICollectionViewCell{

private let container:UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    return view
}()

public let timeLabel:UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular", size: 18)
    label.textColor = .systemBlue
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)

    self.backgroundColor = .green

    self.addSubview(container)
    container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    container.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    container.addSubview(timeLabel)
    timeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    timeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

And this is my CollectionViewController

```
class TimeSelectServiceController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

var timeAvailableArray = [String]()
var timeTitle = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)

    setupCollectionView()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.updateCollectionView()
}

func setupCollectionView(){

    let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 25, bottom: 80, right: 25)
    collectionView.contentInset = inset

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.bottom
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(TimeAvailabilityCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    collectionView.register(SectionTitleHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionTitleHeader")

    collectionView.allowsSelection = true
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    timeAvailableArray.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TimeAvailabilityCell
    let model = timeAvailableArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.timeLabel.text = model.description
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 50)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let reusableview = UICollectionReusableView()
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        //FOR HEADER VIEWS
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionTitleHeader", for: indexPath) as! SectionTitleHeader

        headerView.title.text = timeTitle
        headerView.seeAll.isHidden = true
        headerView.backgroundColor = .white
        return headerView
    default:
        return reusableview
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if(section == 0){
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let model = timeAvailableArray[indexPath.row]

    BookServiceDetails.details.serviceDate = timeTitle + " at " + model.description

    let viewController = ConfirmAppointmentController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}




func updateCollectionView () {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

}

> EDIT

It seems like the more cells I have the harder it is to click on one.

Comment: If you want selection to work correctly, the content of the cell shouldn't be tappable. That means your `container` should have `isUserIneractionEnabled` set to `false`.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should activate constraints in batches rather than one by one. You can do this with [`NSLayoutConstraint.activate(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate).

Comment: @Sulthan I tried that as well but there was still problems. Also it is already set to false. When I Initialized the view

Comment: haha I know, prolly makes my life easier @fphilipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TimeAvailabilityCell` add the sub-views to the `contentView` instead of the `self`.
Disabling user-interaction on the sub-views should not matter.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell):
"To configure the appearance of your cell, **add the views** needed to present the data item’s content **as subviews** to the view **in the contentView** property. Do not directly add subviews to the cell itself."

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)

    self.backgroundColor = .green

    contentView.addSubview(container)
    container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    container.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    container.addSubview(timeLabel)
    timeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    timeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

This:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.updateCollectionView()
    }

    func updateCollectionView () {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

Creates an endless loop, calling `reloadData` on the collection-view, triggers `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Basically the collection-view is reloading the cells constantly, which causes selecting cell to work poorly.

The following blogs are a good reference on how-to setup and work with collection-views; either with storyboards or programmatically. It should give some more insights in how-to setup and configure your collection-view.

- [UICollectionView guide](https://theswiftdev.com/2018/04/17/ultimate-uicollectionview-guide-with-ios-examples-written-in-swift/)
- [UICollectionView Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Hi I tried this out, but it still seemed to not work as good. The function is still not getting called.

Comment: I have it to space out the cells to 3 columns. I forgot to revert it back because I was just checking if the cell size was the reason why it won't read the function. Also I removed it and it just shows the cells side by side and still won't let me click  properly

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how this has anything to do with it but I removed `collectionView.dataSource = self` and everything works fine now.

Comment: There is probably a good explanation to it... have you seen my updated answer, about the endless loop by reloading the data? Could you remove the methods viewDidLayoutSubviews and updateCollectionView. This should not be necessary.

Comment: @EelcoKoelewijn You were actually right. Thank you.